# How to detect screen capture is canceled?

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

I'v activated screen capture by simulate shortcut "cmd-shift-ctrl-4".

```
CGEventRef keyEventDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL,keyCode,true);
CGEventSetFlags(keyEventDown,flags);
CGEventRef keyEventUp = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, keyCode, false);
CGEventSetFlags(keyEventUp,flags);

CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, keyEventDown);  
CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, keyEventUp);
```

and set up a NSTimer to check pasteboard's changeCount. if "changeCount" has changed, means capture was done.

But the problem is , if I press ESC to cancel screen capture, timer didn't know that, it will continue to check the pasteboard. So, How to detect screen capture is canceled ?

Comment: Note that the screen capture can also be cancelled by clicking a mouse button (instead of dragging a rectangle). It would probably be more robust to implement your own screen capture mechanism, especially as the keyboard shortcut for initiating a screen capture could also be changed by the user in the system preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of starting the screenshot by pressing a hard-coded key sequence (which, as omz noted in his comment, may be the wrong one), use NSTask to run [screencapture](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/screencapture.1.html). If the process exits without having created its output file, the user canceled.